# windows .bat files. How to compare 2 folders and generate a return code for the comparison result?

Tags: command-line, batch-file

In a .bat file I need to compare 2 folders and exit the .bat file if there is any difference between these folders.

Unfortunately, `comp` and `windiff` don't provide explicit return codes for different results of comparison. Is there any another way to process results of `comp` or `windiff` to implement the logic described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`comp` sets errorlevel to 1 if file (sets) are diferrent. 
You can test it with `if errorlevel` (`help if` to read details) or you could use
`cmd && cmd_to_execute_if_successful`
`cmd || cmd_to_execute_if_unsuccessful` (`comp folderA folderB || exit /b` in your case)

Comment: Thank you, wmz. I feel embarrassed that I didn't find information on return codes myself )

Comment: Actually the above example won't work with `comp` because after comparing files, but before exiting, it asks `Compare more files (Y/N) ? ` and waits for a responce. I usually call it like this: `echo n | comp filea fileb`.

Comment: @JamesK I left it out for brevity and as a small exercise for reader, but yes, to run it without user interaction, you would need to supply 'confirmation' as you've shown (which may be different for different language versions by the way)

Answer (score 1):

Actually both `comp` and `fc` will return an errorlevel, they are both just a bit noisy. So it's best to pipe their output into `nul`.

```
:: Comp asks a Y/N question via `stderr` (stream2)
:: Comp prints the differences between files on `stdout` (stream1)
:: So we answer the question, and divert both streams to `nul`
echo n | comp dir1 dir2 > nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel%==0 (
  echo The directories are the same.
) else (
  echo The directories are different.
)

:: FC simply outputs the differences between the files via `stdout`
:: So it's only nessicary to redirect `stdout` (stream1) to nul
fc dir1\* dir2\* > nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
  echo The directories are the same.
) else (
  echo The directories are different.
)
```

Or, as wmz pointed out...

```
echo n | comp dir1 dir2 > nul 2>&1 && cmd_to_execute_if_successful
```

and

```
fc dir1\* dir2\* > nul || cmd_to_execute_if_unsuccessful
```

Although, IMHO that coding is so noisy it's a bit hard to read

**NOTE:** `FC` does a binary compare, usually not a problem, but you can specify ASCII text by adding the `/L` switch. (`fc /l dir1\*.txt dir2\*.txt`)

Also remember don't confuse `NUL` with `NULL`, they are not the same.